# I'm Doing the Brackey's RPG Tutorial and Player Controller Script won't work :(

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm Doing the Brackey's RPG playlist, working on the first video about Movement. I'm stuck because I wrote the script exactly like in the video however the console Log says Input has no definition. I need a simple Debug.log function to execute. Help :(

*In the console log*

```
Assets\PlayerController.cs(18,19): error CS0117: 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'GetMouseDown'
```

*Code*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera cam;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Debug.Log("We hit " + hit.collider.name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code and the console log to help explain what is going on.

Comment: @fizzybear Just did! I'm a Unity Noob and I know the video is 2 years old and I have the newer version of Unity so I am not sure if any of the code is deprecated like uNet was

Comment: GetMouseDown change to GetMouseButtonDown

Comment: @Thewonderingnoob You should take a look at the docs.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html. I believe you can also see the source files of `Input` by pressing F12 on Windows.

Comment: @fizzybear thanks that helped! And yeah I was using the wrong phrase for the Input library!

Comment: @TimChang and yeah I def was using the incorrecting phrasing, however when I tried use 0 in the GetMouseButton definition it didn't work but Fire1 did because it was in the unity project settings , can I change it back to a zero?